# How to display a piece of code in Flutter keeping all indentations and newlines as-is?

Tags: flutter

I am making a small programming app and for some examples I need to display some pieces of C code. How does one keep all indentations and newlines('\n') without parsing/messing with them, and display them as in the original code?

I've tried enclosing them in triple-quotes but the indentations are unreliable and it still parses the newlines. The best I've tried is making a horizontal scrolling SingleChildScrollView for displaying lines longer than the viewport, and it works pretty good except for the above formatting issue.

Some Code of the Widget I'm using:

```
class CodeCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const CodeCard({
    Key key,
    this.title,
    this.code,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final String code;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Color.fromRGBO(211, 211, 211, 0.6),
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 5.0, 15.0, 5.0),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Container(
          width: 600.0,
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 15.0, 5.0, 15.0),
          child: new RichText(
            text: new TextSpan(
              children: <TextSpan>[
                new TextSpan(
                  text: title,
                  style: _titleListStyle,
                ),
                new TextSpan(
                  text: code,
                  style: _codeStyle,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For example, this code:

```
CodeCard(code: '''
    void push(int value){
       if(top == SIZE-1)
          printf("\nOverflow error. Stack is Full");
       else{
          top++;
          stack[top] = value;
          printf("\nInsertion was successful");
       }
    }
'''),
```

would produce something like this:

[example of the card displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09tEQ.jpg)

Indentation seems fine in this small code but the newlines are being parsed. One way to overcome this is to remove all the newlines altogether but this is tedious for large pieces of code. I just wanted a faster alternative.

Comment: What is the current result (screenshot)? Please show some code.

Comment: You probably want to research RichText widgets.

Comment: Looks like you need to increase `width` of the container.

Comment: @jdv How do I use a Richtext exactly in this situation? The text to be passed in the Text() will still be a string and newlines would still be parsed.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The `width` of value 600.0 is just to stop the `SingleChildScrollView` from scrolling horizontally infinitely. The final code displayed is broken up because of the parsing of the newlines in the string passed to `TextSpan`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display `\n` as `\n`, then you need to either make the string a raw string, so that escape sequences are not resolved, or use double backslash (`\\n`) to escape the backslash to render it as-is.

Either use

```
CodeCard(code: r'''
    void push(int value){
       if(top == SIZE-1)
          printf("\nOverflow error. Stack is Full");
       else{
          top++;
          stack[top] = value;
          printf("\nInsertion was successful");
       }
    }
'''),
```

(raw strings don't support string interpolation)

or

```
CodeCard(code: '''
    void push(int value){
       if(top == SIZE-1)
          printf("\\nOverflow error. Stack is Full");
       else{
          top++;
          stack[top] = value;
          printf("\\nInsertion was successful");
       }
    }
'''),
```

Comment: That helped, I didn't know about raw strings. Thanks!